# How does mod_wsgi handle requests (in daemon mode)?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am building a Bottle wsgi application and trying to understand how mod_wsgi handles each http request for the wsgi script file.

Does each request use a separate process until the script has completed (and then release it) or can one process handle multiple requests with threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is possible. See the [mod_wsgi docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading) on this question. I believe the default is to use 15 threads and 1 process. The [WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) configuration directive allows you to control this in Apache.